# Upload image in specific folder php Cloudinary

Tags: php, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload images to folders in my cloudinary account but I can't get it to work, it always saves to the default `home` folder.

I have two folders in there called `categories` and `products`.

This is what I have right now

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload(
    $request->file('image'),
    $options = array('public_id' => '/home/categories/' . $request->name . '.' .$extension)
);
```

I also did `'/categories/' . $request->name . '.' .$extension`

I get this

> Cloudinary\Error
> public_id (/home/categories/asdasdf.jpg) is invalid

The docs are here, I can't see what I'm doing wrong
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is like this

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload(
    $request->file('image'),
   $options = array('public_id' => 'categories/' . $request->name)
);
```

This saves the file at `/home/categories/file`